How test functionalities of a method that accepts a YES/NO answer from the UI? NUnit TestFramework
I am writing unit tests for a class, and two methods in the class accepts an answer from the UI. The tests run smooth but a UI element is called every time the test runs and I would have to click the message box manually and run the tests. I need to find a way to run the tests without calling the UI element. Is there a feature in the NUnit test framework to not invoke any UI functions?
I passed an extra boolean into the method just for the purpose of testing but my supervisor told me that was not ideal and I have to find another way to do it.

Which UI framework do you use? WinForms, WPF, MAUI, something else?

winForms. Sorry I did'nt mention that.
